# Different Tables, Same ID's data skip in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables. One table contains questions. The second table is for saving answers from users with the question ID and user ID. If `quiz_answer` table has question ID match with `quiz` question ID, then this question not shown in the quiz table questions list.

Here are Model methods for show questions with pagination.

```
public function quizs($start,$end)
{
    $this->db->select()
             ->from('quiz')
             ->limit($start,$end);
    $data = $this->db->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}
public function posts_count()
{
    $this->db->select('quiz_ID')
             ->from('quiz');
    $data = $this->db->get();
    return $data->num_rows();
}
```

Here is Controller method for showing questions.

```
public function quiz($start=0)
{
    $data['questions'] = $this->quiz->quizs(1,$start);
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'student/quiz/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->quiz->posts_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['solved'] = $this->quiz->bio_question_solved();
    $this->load->view('student/bio_quiz',$data);
}
```

Comment: Elaborate with an example

Comment: which fields you want to select in ```function quizs($start,$end)```?

Comment: Question and Options.